# Why is NextAuth sign in form URL 0.0.0.0:3000 instead of the host header?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

When using next-auth (v5 beta 13) with NextJS 14.1.0 running in kubernetes behind nginx ingress controller the next-auth signin form points to a wrong provider signin url: "http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/auth/signin/auth0".
The host header is "localhost". I would expect the signin url to be "http://localhost/api/auth/signin/auth0" instead. Why is next-auth not using the host header?